# Get epoch millis from local date and timezone

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have two string variables:

```
String localDateTime = "19700101000000";
String timeZone = "+0000";
```

How can i get epoch millis from them using Java 8?

I've already tried that way:

```
private static Long getBeginConnectionTime(
    String dateWithTimeZone = localDateTime  + timeZone ;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssXXXXX");
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateWithTimeZone, formatter);
    return offsetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
)
```

But this code throws exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '19700101000000+0000' could not be parsed at index 14

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
```

Comment: One 'X' represents multiple characters. It's failing because it think you're going to provide 5 timezones. Also I believe you actually want a Z. [See what the characters refer to here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: FYI: You have a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), not a time zone. I would rename that `timezone` variable to `offset` for clarity. A time zone is a historical collection of past, present, and future changes to a region’s offset-from-UTC. A time zone takes the form of `continent/region` such as `Europe/Paris`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just one `X` for the entire timezone number.

So, your format becomes:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssX
```

As the documentation says, however:

> X: zone-offset - 'Z' for zero

So you should use

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssZ
```

Answer (score 2):

[BackSlash’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024275/5772882) is correct. The documentation says about offset X: “Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'.” I take this to mean that 5 Xs also requires a colon in the input string when parsing.

So here’s just my € 0.02 supplement: Since you have two strings, I would find it conceptually simpler to parse each of them and combine the results, than to concatenate the strings and parse the whole. Also if one of the strings contains something unexpected, if you parse them individually, it will be simpler to tell which one was wrong.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(localDateTime, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.of(timeZone))
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
```

A final detail, unless you have a compeling reason, I recommend that your method returns a primitive `long` rather than a `Long` object.

Comment: Thanks, that was usefull.